# Installing more cygwin packages without using setup

Tags: cygwin, windows-xp, expect

I have a Virtual Machine entirely devoted only to VPN connections to different servers. I cannot make any modification on it or I risk to lose some configurations that are needed for some VPNs.
In this VM (Windos XP 32bit based) there is already a cygwin installed. I want to install also the expect package in order to run automatic scripts for testing the VPN connections, but if I run the setup command, nearly at the end of the update process a "cancelSynchronousio cannot be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll" error is shown and from then on I cannot use cygwin anymore: any time I try to launch cygwin the same error is shown.

Now the question: is there a way to add a cygwin package without running the setup command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install manually the older package. As it seldom changes, depending on the architecture they should be:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/x86/release/expect/expect-5.45-1.tar.bz2
http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/x86_64/release/expect/expect-5.45-2.tar.bz2

assuming the 32bit and that you are able to download it in some way

```
tar -xf expect-5.45-1.tar.bz2 -C /
tar -tf expect-5.45-1.tar.bz2 > expect.lst
gzip expect.lst
mv expect.lst.gz /etc/setup
```

and then add a line to /etc/setup/installed.db
with

```
expect expect-5.45-1.tar.bz2 1
```

the file is alphabetically sorted

Comment: This was exactely what I was looking for. But when I launch 'expect' from the command line the result is the following error "C:/cygwin/bin/expect.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libtcl8.5.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I tryied to solve it googling around but I failed

Comment: can I download the tcl-8.5.18-1.tar.xz and follow the same steps you mentioned for the expect tar? Exactely the same (but for the filenames)?

Answer (score 1):

The current cygwin does not work on Windows XP; so it is not only the setup 
that will have problem but also most of the packages.

For your scope you need to use a older version of setup

http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html

and an old version of the packages

Comment: As I said in the post, cygwin is already installed in the VM. I ran the setup.exe that is the same version of the working cygwin, so it is already an older version. I also tried to dowload a 2.874 version from scratch but I lost all the config I needed to use the VPNs, so it is not a viable solution